# Sencha EXT JS tree check/uncheck very slow while filtered

Tags: performance, extjs, tree

Recursive check/uncheck for tree with 116 nodes takes 9-13ms with function:

```
   checkchange: function (record, checked, opts) {
                    var i = 0;
                    var start = new Date();
                    this.suspendLayouts();
                    record.cascadeBy(function (e) {
                        i++;
                        e.set('checked', checked);
                    });
                    this.resumeLayouts();
                    var stop = new Date();
                    alert(i + 'items ' + (stop - start) + 'ms');

                }
```

But if store is filtered by one of the fields this becomes very slow (2000ms).
This is the filter:

```
   load: function () {

                    this.getStore().filter({
                        property: 'account_id',
                        value: 3934,
                        operator: '='
                    });
                   
                }
```

Seems that suspendLayouts not working and every time on  **e.set('checked', checked);** filter processed on all tree and rerender all nodes.

You can check on https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3l62
just comment/uncomment filter code to see difference.
Any way to make it faster?

Answer (score 0):

Found workaround solution that suppress store events during batch update but refresh needed for view after update finished. Before update you must call  **this.getStore().suspendEvents();**
and after:
**this.getStore().resumeEvents();**

and refresh, depending on bufferedRenderer:

```
 if (this.getView().bufferedRenderer) {
     this.getView().bufferedRenderer.refreshView();
 } else {
     this.getView().refresh();
 }
```

Complete code:

```
 checkchange: function (record, checked, opts) {
                    var i = 0;
                    var start = new Date();
                    this.suspendLayouts();
                    this.getStore().suspendEvents();
                    record.cascadeBy(function (e) {
                        i++;
                        e.set('checked', checked);
                    });
                    this.resumeLayouts();
                    this.getStore().resumeEvents();
                    if (this.getView().bufferedRenderer) {
                        this.getView().bufferedRenderer.refreshView();
                    } else {
                        this.getView().refresh();
                    }

                    var stop = new Date();
                    alert(i + 'items ' + (stop - start) + 'ms');

                }
```